# Trying to restore a Craft instance for a customer who was abandoned

Tags: install, installation

I am new to Craft and a client asked us to take over a site as the previous service provider abandoned them.

For now just trying to get up and running on a Windows server in a test environment before deploying to a production server.

After restoring the mySQL db and getting it up and running via IIS the admin works, but the public site gives an error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure
>   named "placeCategory"

Does this imply we don't have the latest db of the site or all the files (or both)? Not sure what this error means or where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Could you please take a look at your fields in your cp and tell us if there is a field with the handle `placeCategory`. This error usually means, that your entryModel doesn't have the field property. We can only assume why because we don't know what you did exactly. Maybe this error was there before but his config settings were set to  `live` mode and you set it to `dev` mode -> live mode does not show errors -> it's not your fault. Maybe you didn't import all the tables properly -> the field layout isn't attached to the entry. Maybe you changed certain templates and so on